# Pivot table: Join same record if one of parameter is empty

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have this Country Label table:

```
Country_Code  |  Product_Code  | Label_Name  | Placement
IT               PR_I01          T-Label       Top Left
IT               PR_I01          Instruction   Bottom Center
HK               PR_H34          Tag           Bottom Left
HK                               HK Label      Bottom Right
US               PR_U12          Sticker       Bottom Center
GB               PR_G16          QR Code       Bottom Right
```

I managed to pivot the table to something like this:

```
Country_Code  |  Product_Code  | Label_Name1  | Placement1      | Label_Name2   | Placement 2 |
IT               PR_I01          T-Label       Top Left           Instruction     Bottom Center
HK               PR_H34          Tag           Bottom Left
HK                               HK Label      Bottom Right
US               PR_U12          Sticker       Bottom Center
GB               PR_G16          QR Code       Bottom Right
```

I want to make the record with an Empty product_code join other record with the same country_code (every product_code for certain country will always use that one same label). So it will be like this

```
Country_Code  |  Product_Code  | Label_Name1  | Placement1      | Label_Name2   | Placement 2 |
HK               PR_H34          Tag            Bottom Left       HK Label        Bottom Right
```

Here my current query:

```
SELECT CODE_COUNTRY,
       PRODUCT_CODE,
       "1_LN" Label_Name1,
       "1_LP" Placement1,
       "2_LN" Label_Name2,
       "2_LP" Placement2
FROM   (WITH CNTRYRWS
               AS (SELECT   CODE_COUNTRY,
                            PRODUCT_CODE,
                            LABEL_NAME,
                            PLACEMENT,                                
                            ROW_NUMBER ()
                               OVER (
                                  PARTITION BY CODE_COUNTRY, product_code
                                  ORDER BY LABEL_NAME, PLACEMENT
                               )
                               RN
                     FROM   PL_COUNTRY_LABEL_V)
        SELECT   *
          FROM   CNTRYRWS PIVOT ( MIN (LABEL_NAME) LN , MIN (
                          PLACEMENT) LP FOR RN IN ( 1 AS "1" , 2
                          AS "2") ))
```

How to achieve such a result?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . Conditional aggregation seems like a simple approach:

```
select country_code, max(product_code) as product_code,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then label_name end) as label_name_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then placement end) as placement_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then label_name end) as label_name_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then placement end) as placement_2
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by country_code
                                order by product_code nulls last, label_name
                               ) as seqnum
      from PL_COUNTRY_LABEL_V c
     ) c
group by country_code
```

Comment: thanks, but if I have more than one product_code with the same country_code lets say I add new HK label with different product_code, I can't call it by using country_code & product_code as parameter since it MAX-ed I guess.

Comment: @Syns . . . This pre-supposes that you know the number of columns in the result set.  If you do not, you have to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: thanks I'll take a look about dynamic SQL, haven't use it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate through use of `MAX()` for all columns except the `Country_Code` column which should be in the `GROUP BY` in the main query after removing `Product_Code` from `PARTITION BY` list such as

```
SELECT Country_Code, 
       MAX(product_code) AS Product_Code,
       MAX("1_LN") AS Label_Name1,
       MAX("1_LP") AS Placement1,
       MAX("2_LN") AS Label_Name2,
       MAX("2_LP") AS Placement2
  FROM (WITH CNTRYRWS AS 
       (
        SELECT Country_Code,
               PRODUCT_CODE,
               LABEL_NAME,
               PLACEMENT,
               ROW_NUMBER() 
               OVER(PARTITION BY Country_Code--, Product_Code 
                        ORDER BY LABEL_NAME, PLACEMENT) RN
          FROM PL_COUNTRY_LABEL_V
         )
        SELECT *
          FROM CNTRYRWS 
         PIVOT 
         ( MIN (LABEL_NAME) LN , 
           MIN (PLACEMENT) LP FOR RN IN ( 1 AS "1" , 2 AS "2") ))
GROUP BY Country_Code
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e98dea92e34e6d251e9fd67b2d70b6f4)</kbd>

Comment: thanks, how if there are more than one product_code with the same country_code? it always return the MAX one.

Comment: Hi @Syns .  As long as the number of product codes for each country is two at most, just as in your case(rn=1 and 2), then no problem will occur as you can see for countries `HK` and `IT`.

Comment: Hi @Ozhan, that's the problem, I'll have a lot more product_code per country_code,  thank you

Comment: @Syns Making it dynamic is not the problem, but your case is getting more complicated. Initially you need to get rid of the extra row for **empty** `product_code` values, now you can have more than one `product_code` (presumably non-null) per each country. In this case, how do you want to put non-null product code along with null product codes ??